# If every sequence that approaches a point $c$ has a codomain limit of $L$, then the limit of the function is also $L$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f$ be a fuction, $D$ its domain, and $c$ a point of it. If we have that

$$\forall (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset D : \lim x_n=c, x_n \neq c \longrightarrow L=\lim f(x_n)$$

That is, all sequences contained in the domain, that approach $c$, have a limit of $L$ in the codomain or range. Then, $L$ is also the limit of $f$.

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)$$

---

I'm trying to prove this by **prove by contradiction**. First of all we have that all sequences that approach $c$ have a codomain limit of $L$, that is:

$$\forall(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, \forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta_o>0,\forall x_n\in D:(0<|x_n - c| < \delta_o \longrightarrow |f(x_n)-L|<\epsilon)$$

And then we make the hypothesis that $L$ is **not** the limit of $f$ as it approaches $c$, that is:

$$\exists\epsilon_o>0,\forall\delta>0,\exists x_o\in D:(0<|x_o - c|<\delta\bigwedge |f(x_o)-L|\geqslant \epsilon_o)$$

I think this should lead to a contradiction but my lack of practice doesn't let me see it. I know that every limit point can be approached by a **sequence**, and since the first condition is valid for all sequences, I've considered **defining** a sequence that approaches that $x_o$, for that value of $\epsilon_o$, but I swear I still can't see the contradiction, even though I think this is the way to prove it.

Can somebody help me finish this off? I think the prove is close to its end but I can't conclude it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: For each positive integer $n,$ putting $\delta_n=\frac1n,$ we have that there is some $x_n\in D$ such that $0<\bigl|x_n-c\bigr|<\delta_n$ and $\bigl|f(x_n)-L\bigr|\geq\epsilon_0.$

Comment: Hmm so I could consider the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}+c$, so that all points verify that $0<|x_n - c|<\delta_n$ and hence it also must be verified that $|f(x_n)-L|<\epsilon$ for all epsilon values, which is a contradiction as it is not verified for $\epsilon_o$. Am I right? Sorry I think my mind is a total mess right now :S

Comment: Unfortunately, since we don't know exactly what $D$ is, we can't specify any of the $x_n.$ What can you say about the behavior of the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ by construction? What does this tell us about its codomain limit, by hypothesis?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it this time. Maybe what has to be done is define the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ for which its respective $x_n$ values are the ones that correspond to each $x_o$ when $\delta_n=\frac{1}{n}$ is assigned as you said, in which case the limit of the sequence would be $c$; which means that on the one hand according to the second assumption $|f(x_n)-L|\geqslant \epsilon_o$, meanwhile on the other hand according to the first one, $|f(x_n)-L|< \epsilon : \forall\epsilon>0$, in particular, lesser than $\epsilon_o$. Is this correct this time?

Comment: You have it almost perfect. By construction, we have that $\bigl|f(x_n)-L\bigr|\ge\epsilon_0$ for *all* positive integers $n.$ On the other hand, for *sufficiently large* positive integers $n,$ we must have $\bigl|f(x_n)-L\bigr|<\epsilon_0.$ Nice work!

Comment: Oh I see the difference, I think I completely understand now. Thanks for all your help Cameron!

Comment: You're very welcome.